2D chunk loading/world generation in Godot (GDScript)
I'm a beginner with both Godot and gamedev concepts. I've made games before, but feature-wise, they were pretty simple in comparison.
One of the main concerns that I have now with my code is that everything in relation to world generation and chunk loading should happen in a separate thread, but I don't want to do that until I know that whatever I've done is correct.
The whole project is over on my github at https://github.com/inexperienced-potat/sandbox
map/world_gen.gd:
extends TileMap

var world_data: Array[Chunk]
var noise: FastNoiseLite = FastNoiseLite.new()
var loaded_chunks: Dictionary

const UNLOAD_CHUNKS_DISTANCE: int = 3
const SURROUNDING_CHUNKS: int = 2

func _ready():
    noise.seed = 12345 #testing value, will be replaced by Time.get_unix_time_from_system()
    noise.noise_type = FastNoiseLite.TYPE_PERLIN
    noise.frequency = 0.005

func generate_chunk(chunk_pos: Vector2i) -> Chunk:
    var noise_data: Dictionary = {}

    for y in range(0, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE):
        for x in range(0, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE):
            var noise_value = noise.get_noise_2d(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE * chunk_pos.x + x, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE * chunk_pos.y + y)
            noise_data[Vector2i(x, y)] = -1 if noise_value < 0 else 1

    var chunk: Chunk = Chunk.new(chunk_pos, noise_data)
    return chunk

func draw_chunk(chunk: Chunk) -> void:
    for y in range(0, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE):
        for x in range(0, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE):
            #skip border tiles, just for chunk visualisation
            #if x == 0 or x == 15 or y == 0 or y == 15:
            #   continue

            var tileset_coords = Vector2i(1, 0) if chunk.data[Vector2i(x, y)] == -1 else Vector2i(0, 0)

            set_cell(0, Vector2i(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE * chunk.position.x + x, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE * chunk.position.y + y), 0, tileset_coords)

func erase_chunk(chunk: Chunk) -> void:
    for y in range(0, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE):
        for x in range(0, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE):
            erase_cell(0, Vector2i(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE * chunk.position.x + x, Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE * chunk.position.y + y))

func write_world_data(path: String):
    # compress world_data
    # save it in a file path
    pass

func read_world_data(path: String):
    # read data from a save file at path
    # decompress that data into world_data
    pass

func compress_data():
    # compress world_data and return it
    pass

func decompress_data():
    # decompress world_data and return it
    pass

func clear_distant_chunks(chunk_pos: Vector2i) -> void:
    var chunk_positions = loaded_chunks.keys()

    for pos: Vector2i in chunk_positions:
        if abs(pos.x - chunk_pos.x) > UNLOAD_CHUNKS_DISTANCE or abs(pos.y - chunk_pos.y) > UNLOAD_CHUNKS_DISTANCE:
            var unloaded_chunk: Chunk = loaded_chunks[pos]

            erase_chunk(unloaded_chunk)
            loaded_chunks.erase(pos)
            unloaded_chunk.queue_free()

# this function is called when player emits changed_chunk signal
func _on_player_changed_chunk(new_pos: Vector2i) -> void:
    for y in range(new_pos.y - SURROUNDING_CHUNKS, new_pos.y + SURROUNDING_CHUNKS + 1):
        for x in range(new_pos.x - SURROUNDING_CHUNKS, new_pos.x + SURROUNDING_CHUNKS + 1):
            var chunk_pos: Vector2i = Vector2i(x, y)

            if chunk_pos not in loaded_chunks.keys():
                var chunk: Chunk = generate_chunk(chunk_pos)

                loaded_chunks[chunk_pos] = chunk
                draw_chunk(chunk)

    clear_distant_chunks(new_pos)

map/chunk.gd:
extends Node

class_name Chunk

var position: Vector2i
var data: Dictionary

const CHUNK_SIZE: int = 16

func _init(chunk_pos: Vector2i, noise_data: Dictionary):
    position = chunk_pos
    data = noise_data
    
# converts world coordinates to chunk coordinates
static func world_pos_to_chunk_pos(world_pos: Vector2) -> Vector2i:
    return Vector2i(
        round(world_pos.x * pow(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE, -2)), 
        round(world_pos.y * pow(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE, -2))
    )

player/player_movement.gd:
extends CharacterBody2D

signal changed_chunk(new_pos: Vector2i)

@export var movement_speed: float = 100
var direction: Vector2
var chunk_pos: Vector2i = Vector2i(0, 0)
var init: bool = true

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity = direction * movement_speed * delta
    move_and_collide(velocity)
    check_chunk_pos()
    
func check_chunk_pos():
    if init:
        changed_chunk.emit(chunk_pos)
        init = false
    
    var old_pos: Vector2i = chunk_pos
    var new_pos: Vector2i = Chunk.world_pos_to_chunk_pos(position)
    
    if old_pos != new_pos:
        chunk_pos = new_pos
        changed_chunk.emit(new_pos)

func _process(_delta):
    direction = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "up", "down")

Any help is very appreciated.
